# ObjectQuery<T> or IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4

I Use ObjectQuery as datasource for a couple of BindingSources in my winforms app.
Problem is that Im used to Linq like queries so I use them defining datasource:

```
View.DsMyDataSource = (from p in ModelContext.GetContext.MyObject 
                       where p.Deleted == false  p) as ObjectQuery<MyObject>;
```

`ModelContext.GetContext()` returns singleton of my modelContext entity.

Is it good way of doing that ? I'm afraid that using LINQ like queries I may loose something because of cast.

Is there any other way I can get ObjectQuery type using linq syntax ?

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: If people dont answer my question properly why should I lie that its answer ?

Comment: You can Mark as answer, answer which helps you to find the exact answer, people spend time for free to help you and this is a simple gift to them.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that belated answer mark.  It was a good answer, no idea why you waited so long.  Being a bit sloppy about it?  It's a small effort, really.

Comment: Sorry for that, now I will mark answers as answered as soon as these are correct not the best I would wish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well actually `ObjectQuery<T>` *implements* `IQueryable<T>`, so there is no real difference.

I would advise to not bind to an IQueryable, as this is giving too much power to the UI. The point of IQueryable is to defer execution of queries to a later point in time (such as a BLL, services layer), but presentation IMO is too late.

When i say it is too late, i mean that by the time the query gets to the UI, no more queries against the database should be made. But if the UI starts performing operations such as `.Count()` or `.Sum()`, you have 2 queries executed. Makes it very difficult to dispose of your data context.

My advice, return a concrete collection: e.g `ICollection<T>`, and bind to that.

If you need to do things like paging, then do that via LINQ `.Skip()` and `.Take()`.